# Include issues with matlab_add_mex and Cmake

Tags: matlab, cmake, mex

Everyone, i've been struggling a bit with this issue. I have to build a mex file (.mexw64) with CMake. Everything works fine under simulink, i'm able to use

```
mex -ImyLib mySrc.cpp
```

But when i'm using CMake:

```
find_package(myLib)
find_package(Matlab)
matlab_add_mex(NAME cmake_mySrc.mexw64 SRC mySrc.cpp LINK_TO myLib::myLib)
```

I've got the following issue :

```
fatal error: simstruc.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand because find_package(Matlab) should import the simstruct.h  isn't it ?

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact we need to require Simulink in order to load Simstruc.h

```
find_package(myLib)
find_package(Matlab REQUIRED SIMULINK)
matlab_add_mex(NAME cmake_mySrc.mexw64 SRC mySrc.cpp LINK_TO myLib::myLib)
```